# Can I call curl_slist_free_all right after I set CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER?

Tags: c, libcurl

Can I do this?

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
```

That is, can I free the header list before I send the request? Does curl make a copy?

Comment: Just a note for the future: If you run into a 3rd party binary library and you can't look and see, what you can do is set the option, then overwrite your value with something obvious and then call the operation. If the original value shows up you know it made a copy. If the new value shows up, you know it didn't.

Comment: This is now also clarified in the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER man page for future hackers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. In the source the setopt function just saves your pointer.

```
case CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER:
    /*
     * Set a list with HTTP headers to use (or replace internals with)
     */
    data->set.headers = va_arg(param, struct curl_slist *);
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

And additionally the list should live during the lifetime of the program, or at least until everything is done with the curl_perform.